# Why is ARCore not working for face tracking in Unity AR Foundation?

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcore, ar-foundation

I am developing an AR app in unity that uses Ar Foundation and Google ARcore Xr plugin to detect a face and apply a 3d model on it using the face mananger script. I've encountered some issues with ARCore not working properly.
Few weeks ago everything worked as expected but a few days ago when I ran the app, it prompted for me to update the Google Services for Ar(Arcore). After that nothing worked regarding face tracking. I even tested the samples provided here "https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/arfoundation-samples#face-tracking "but encountered the same issues.

I tried updating all the plugins used in my app, checked dependencies and compatibility with my device.